# Transmission permission denied in docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, docker-compose, transmission-daemon

I am trying to use transmission in docker with the following docker-compose.yml file by running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

```
version: "3.6"
services:
    transmission:
            image: lsioarmhf/transmission
            container_name: Transmission
            volumes: 
                    - ${USERDIR}/docker/transmission:/config
                    - ${USERDIR}/files/downloads/complete:/downloads/complete
                    - ${USERDIR}/files/downloads/incomplete:/downloads/incomplete
                    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
            ports: 
                    - "9091:9091"
                    - "51413:51413"
                    - "51413:51413/udp"
            restart: always
            environment:
                    - PUID=${PUID}
                    - PGID=${PGID}
                    - TZ=${TZ}
                    - TRANSMISSION_DOWNLOAD_DIR=${USERDIR}/files/downloads
```

After adding a .torrent file using the web ui at `localhost:9091` "Error: Permission Denied (/home/pi/files/downloads)" is displayed. I have tried to remedy this using `sudo chown pi:debian-transmission /home/pi/files/downloads -R` and `sudo chown pi:docker /home/pi/files/downloads -R` to no avail. I have also tried running transmission as root through docker by removing the PUID and PGID environmental variables from the file. However this poses another error saying "Error: Unable to save resume file: Permission denied"

I am at a loss on how to fix this, does anyone know a way to get it to work?

Comment: Ran into a similar issue with kubernetes(microk8s[v1.23.6 classic]) on 2 Nodes(the Pi's) -- turns out the pods(app containers) and the file system were running on different nodes.Pods on Node A and hostPath(External HDD mounted on Node B host). Fixed it by condorning one node leaving only one node (the one with the file system) available during scheduling. Took a while to figure that one out. Planning to move to NFS storage. Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

Taking a wild swing. Do your directories allow write access to the relevant users?
`ls -la /home/pi/files/downloads`
See what permissions are there